# ExtJS 4.1 - Override css of Ext.LoadMask

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, loadmask

I have a requirement to override the default background color of `Ext.LoadMask` from white to grey. How can I achieve this? Also adding the screenshot of the image and the code that I am using to load the mask.

[image: My Mask]

```
var feestore = this.getBillingFeePanelStoreStore();
        feestore.on({
            beforeload: this.beforeFeestoreLoad,
            scope: this
        });

beforeFeestoreLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts){
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait.... Your request is being processed"});
    myMask.show();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '[maskCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-cfg-maskCls)' to define your own style, then add appropriate css

```
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait.... Your request is being processed", maskCls:'customLoadMask'});

CSS:
    .customLoadMask {
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        opacity: .7;
        background: grey !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks newmount for the suggestion but this doesn't work. I don't see the default cls being overridden.

Comment: not sure what went wrong, but here is a fiddle where it works: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/196

Comment: when creating mask with new Ext.LoadMask... 'maskCls' is not getting applied... here is a workaround : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2do

Comment: Could you please correct these 3 last lines  // Somehow adding maskCls not working, so
            var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.x-mask');
            var el = Ext.get(dom[0]);
            el.addCls('customLoadMask');  as per sencha jsfiddle jslint

Comment: Thanks newmount, this is now running perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on extjs 4.2:
**msgCls** instead of **maskCls**

```
var loadingMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {
msg:"Een moment geduld aub ...", msgCls:'msgClsCustomLoadMask'});
```

CSS:

```
.msgClsCustomLoadMask{
background-color: #FF0000;
border: solid 2px #A3BAD9;}

.msgClsCustomLoadMask .x-mask-msg-inner{
color: #000066;
font: normal 25px Times new Roman,helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif;}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-cfg-msgCls

Hope this helps.